# Password not working on time machine restore after clean install

Tags: backup, restore, password

So I recently wiped my computer clean because it had some problems, and did a clean install of Lion from a flash drive. I then restored my user from a time machine back up originally made from my laptop. When I transferred the account over, my password didn't work. The same password I used to log onto this account on this computer I'm using (my laptop) did not work on the account on the desktop I restored this laptop to.

This is the second time I have gone through this process and I am thoroughly frustrated. There is a single account on my computer that I cannot log into. I don't know what to do, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I've been through the same pain. Firstly time machine wont restore. Then transfer files and settings doesn't leave a working account. Do apple test their software? Thoroughly unimpressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from the recovery partition (hold cmd+r while the system starts up).  Once you get to the options, there should be a utilities menu.  Open terminal, and you'll be given a command prompt.  Type "resetpassword".  You should be able to figure it out from there!